# Remove bold style from japanese characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts

I am generating one PDF in ruby on rails
filename is abc.html.haml

the file contains Japanese characters that I have copied from a word document.

Now the problem is that some Japanese characters in pdf are displayed with bold style but I have not added any Style or CSS for the characters.
This makes my PDF look uneven some characters are normal some are bold.

If anyone can help me 
Thank you in advance

[image]

As it can be seen in screenshot some characters are bold

Comment: Can you add pdf here?

Comment: I added one screenshot to show. Is that ok?

Comment: is it come from database?

Comment: Did you try another font?

Comment: Are you sure that's the "bold version" and not just bad rasterization making things look completely wrong? Generate your document at a larger point size (e.g. 48 instead of 12 or 16) and see if things look fine. If they do: that PDF generator has bugs in its shaping engine.